# How to include promises in vuejs methods

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, es6-promise

The code below has vuejs methods. One is calling another through the promise function. How can I make `handleStart` be invoked first, then once done is true, `foo` will be resolve, and `handleStart` will finish. **The start button must be clicked first**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <button
            @click="handleStart"
            >
            START
        </button>
        <button
        @click="done = true"
        >DONE</button>
        <h1>Start the app: {{start}}</h1>
        <h1>Is it done? {{done}}</h1>


    </div>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app', 
            data () {
                return {
                    start: false,
                    done:false 
                }
            }, 
            methods: {
                foo() {
                    return new Promise( (resolve) => {
                        if (this.done) {
                            console.log("done is recorded")
                            resolve("Yaa")
                        }
                    })
                }, 
                handleStart () {
                    this.start = true
                    // how to make this an obsersable 
                    this.foo()
                        .then( (data ) => console.log("I must be printed with:", data))
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't understand, it is already async with the `then`. Nothing happens after `this.foo()` is called in `handleStart`

Comment: sry. i guess the right word will be how to make it an observable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `if (this.done)` check.
When `done` is false, the promise is never resolved, and the handleStart never receives data.

If you need to react when a `data` has changed, take a look Vue's [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use watchers to watch `this.done` change

```
watch: {
  done(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}, 
methods: {
  async handleStart () {
    // how to make this async
    this.start = true
    const data = await this.foo()
    console.log("I must be printed with:", data))
  }
}
```

Comment: so basically what you are saying is I cant make observables within methods? sry async was not the right word. because once `await this.foo()` is done, i want to `console.log`

this was what i did with your suggestion but doesnt work
https://hastebin.com/pisajotaha.xml